# struct.unpack 6 bytes into short and int fails. Why?

Tags: python

```
s = '\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
struct.unpack('hi',s)
```

I expect to get (1,2), but instead get the error:

```
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

If I perform the two unpacks separately it works:

```
myshort = struct.unpack('h',s[:2])
myint = struct.unpack('i',s[2:])
```

Also, interestingly, it will accept it if the format string is 'ih' instead of 'hi'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [`C` structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86). If you actually want your data items to remain unaligned, prefix a `=` sign before the formatted string

```
>>> s = '\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack('=hi',s)
(1, 2)
```

Refer the documentation [7.3.2.1. Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)